Does Peacemaker's Brony quip reference something specific about Green Arrow?
In the DCEU TV series Peacemaker (2022) S01E08 "It's Cow or Never," there's a scene where the titular character (played by John Cena) quips that Green Arrow

goes to Brony conventions dressed as the back half of Twilight Sparkle with a four-inch-wide butthole drilled in the costume.

This quip seems to associate Green Arrow with some of the negative stereotypes surrounding the My Little Pony fandom, particularly the adult male fans known as "Bronies."
I get most of Peacemaker's jabs at other DC superheroes. For instance, he jokes that Aquaman has sex with fish, which plays on Aquaman's powers. He also calls the Flash (Barry Allen) an "unbearable d-bag," which seems to reference the character's personality. These jabs feel specific to those heroes.
But the Green Arrow joke, I'm not so sure about. It feels like you could replace "Green Arrow" with any other superhero, and the insult would still work. Is there something about Green Arrow that makes this joke particularly fitting for him? Am I missing some aspect of his character or history that Peacemaker might be referencing?
Does this joke and/or insult actually relate to something specific about Green Arrow, or is it just a random insult Peacemaker made?
